# Interpretation of WWI Marine Muster Log

Tags: united-states, military-records, world-war-1

See the image below. I'm trying to understand what this is saying, particularly the "12"-16" and the reference to "22 Trans to Repl Bn". also what does "GO 100 does not apply auth GO 111"

[image]

Comment: There's nothing attached.  Can you try again?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE! AS a new user be sure to take the 2-minute [Tour] that introduces you to the site.  There's an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to open it up and then a picture button above it to browse to an image so that you can include it.

Comment: It would be useful to know what country's records were being discussed, even without the image.

Comment: @ Jan Murphy: from US Muster Rolls of Marine Corps 1798-1937, dated Sept 1 thru Sept 30 1918, in category "Transferred' sub-listing "National Naval Volunteers"

Comment: 12"-16"  "might mean foot as in 12th Foot. or could mean he was enlisted between 1912-1916. I believe GO is General Order. IE: a document giving instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I may have some info for you.  Browsing through the document you seem to be looking at (but not the specific page)

[United States, Muster Rolls of the Marine Corps, 1798-1937](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3QS7-L98P-VHMB?owc=collection%2F1916228%2Fwaypoints&wc=SYPZ-4WR%3A1516642801%2C1514701401%3Fcc%3D1916228&cc=1916228)

seems to show this is some form of monthly log.  The other numeric entries would appear to correspond to days of the month. I am guessing that the numbers with quotes indicate actual combat days.

Which means this 22 is the date of the transfer to the Replacement Battalion (Bn).

GO is General Order, and GO 100 is concerning record keeping requirements, while GO 111 is concerning replacement troops:

> In addition to the combat divisions assigned to each corps and the
>   corps troops. a Replacement Battalion will be organized in each corps.
>   This battalion is under the command of the corps commander and will be
>   designated as the " __ Corps Replacement Battalion."

The above is from pg. 386 of [UNITED STATES ARMY
IN THE WORLD WAR
1917-1919
General Orders, GHQ, AEF
Volume 16](http://www.history.army.mil/html/books/023/23-22/CMH_Pub_23-22.pdf)